# When I overlay two artists on the same position, the lowest one still somehow shows

Tags: python, matplotlib

The code below draws

- a red rectangle
- a yellow rectangle with a red one on top of it
- a yellow rectangle

This results in the following image

[image]

I would assume that the second rectangle would look exactly the same as the first, red, rectangle since it's alpha value is 1 and hence nothing of the underlying yellow rectangle should be visible.

Am I missing something? Is it possible to solve this?

Thanks in advance,

Marc

Code used:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

fig = plt.figure()
axes = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

rect = Rectangle((0.2, 0.2), 0.1, 0.6)
rect.set_fill(False)
rect.set_edgecolor((1, 0, 0, 1))
axes.add_artist(rect)

rect = Rectangle((0.4, 0.2), 0.1, 0.6)
rect.set_fill(False)
rect.set_edgecolor((1, 1, 0, 1))
axes.add_artist(rect)

rect = Rectangle((0.4, 0.2), 0.1, 0.6)
rect.set_fill(False)
rect.set_edgecolor((1, 0, 0, 1))
axes.add_artist(rect)

rect = Rectangle((0.6, 0.2), 0.1, 0.6)
rect.set_fill(False)
rect.set_edgecolor((1, 1, 0, 1))
axes.add_artist(rect)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Rectangles are not precisely positionned on pixel of the resulting image and their linewidth is no integer multiple of a pixel. A common technique to make images still look decent in computer graphics is to use antialiasing. This will result in nice images, but will inevitably lead to the result you observe.

You may however turn antialiasing off.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

fig = plt.figure()
axes = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

rect = Rectangle((0.2, 0.2), 0.1, 0.6, antialiased=False)
rect.set_fill(False)
rect.set_edgecolor((1, 0, 0, 1))
axes.add_artist(rect)

rect = Rectangle((0.4, 0.2), 0.1, 0.6, antialiased=False)
rect.set_fill(False)
rect.set_edgecolor((1, 1, 0, 1))
axes.add_artist(rect)

rect = Rectangle((0.4, 0.2), 0.1, 0.6, antialiased=False)
rect.set_fill(False)
rect.set_edgecolor((1, 0, 0, 1))
axes.add_artist(rect)

rect = Rectangle((0.6, 0.2), 0.1, 0.6, antialiased=False)
rect.set_fill(False)
rect.set_edgecolor((1, 1, 0, 1))
axes.add_artist(rect)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! 
(and some additional characters to reach the minimum of 15 characters before I can express my gratitude :-) )